How to use python in electron js package
My friend and I are buildinf a desktop app using electron js, in there we have a snippet of code that runs in a js file that goes like this:
const scriptPath = await window.spawnAPI.pathJoin('..', '..', 'python_scripts', 'analyse.py');
const result = window.spawnAPI.spawn('python', [scriptPath, text]);
return result;`

We thought that this would be enough to run the python script analyse.py in the program and it does work when we run it via npm start. But when we use npm run make to make the package, the program runs into an error, saying the file analyse.py does not exist. Can anyone explain how do we do fix this error?
We already tried using pyinstaller to transform the analyse.py into an exe file but that also does not work.

You're assuming a specific working directory,  Are you 100% certain that's where your app runs?  You're also assuming that the computer has Python installed.  Most do not.

first use may have to use /full/path/to/python and /full/path/to/analyse.py. Relative path may not work if some program will run it from different folder. Other problem is to add Python to your package - and this can be big challenge.
